# Override CSS with PHP doesn't show same result

Tags: php, css

I just noticed this weird thing.  So I have a master CSS document, and I'm overriding one section in it with a PHP variable that I include at the beginning of my index.php to dynamically change a background image based on whats in a folder on the server.

In typical CSS I have this:

```
.fullscreen{
    background: url('./Hero_Image/image01.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
}
```

And I have a nice, full-screen image background for the .fullscreen class section that is scaled appropriately for the browser window and scales as the window is resized.

However, when I try to make this dynamic, using php and overriding like so:

```
<?php
    include '_SiteResources/php/loadHeroImage.php'; //<< note:  output is basically an echo of the URL of the first file in a folder
?>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fullscreen{ background: url('<?php getHeroImage(); ?>') no-repeat center center;}
    </style>
</head>
```

I'm noticing overriding using PHP isn't showing the same result.  Yes, its also fullscreen, but I'm noticing it also doesn't scale as the window scales, like the original CSS implementation; it seems to display scaled up, and doesn't scale with the browser window.

Why is that?

---

Here's the code for loadHeroImage.php per request:

```
<?php
function getHeroImage(){

    $h = opendir('./Hero_Image/'); //Open the current directory
    while (false !== ($heroImage = readdir($h))) {
        if($heroImage != '.' && $heroImage != '..') { //Skips over . and ..
            $heroFileInfo = pathinfo($heroImage);
            $heroImagePath = $heroFileInfo['dirname'];
            $heroImageBase = $heroFileInfo['basename'];
            // $heroImageFullPath = $heroImagePath.$heroImageBase;
            echo './Hero_Image/'.$heroImageBase.' ';
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the (HTML) output of the php implementation? Is it different from the static CSS implementation?

Comment: post the code in loadHeroImage.php

Comment: also, if you had error reporting on you would notice that this is throwing an error for the missing semicolon that should be behind it.. `getHeroImage()`

Comment: U need to terminate yur php line or use short code as my other mate said.

Comment: Edited question to include my code for my php function.

Comment: i suggest you to use ajax request for that. it will be much better

Comment: Just for testing echo './Hero_Image/image01.jpg'; in your function and close other code u will get the better idea hard code yur img path in function

Comment: @Pamblam: never got an issue with the missing semicolon.  It still technically works whether I have it or not.  The bigger issue is why is the scaling not working when overriding with PHP vs. hardcoding file path of image with CSS.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar: both CSS and PHP should output the same thing.  The php is literally just echoing a URL to the first file in a folder, followed by typical CSS modifiers (no-repeat, center center;).  The CSS version just has a hard-coded URL to a specific file.

Comment: Yur folder name is wrong

Comment: @dotcommer, is it actually echoing the same HTML? In that case it should display exactly the same, unless a different backgorund image is set.

Comment: Now I am removing my answer. Try to test by using hard code value in function ...

Comment: @EduardoEscobar: yeah, its the same HTML, which is why I'm so confused.  It should be working exactly the same as in CSS.  The only difference is I'm substituting a dynamic URL with PHP instead of hardcoding it.  `.fullscreen` is a class of a section tag, but I have no modifiers for section tags in my CSS.

Comment: The thing that is confusing me is that your css code shouldn't cause it to scale no matter what you do to generate the path. Your css definition will just set the background image to not repeat and position it in the center horizontally and vertically. By default, background images don't scale. You need to set the `background-size` property. [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images).

Comment: @andrew: Sorry, I'm realizing I haven't been clear about this.  I just discovered why i'm getting this discrepancy.  I do have `background-size` set, but I didn't realize that I needed to include that when overriding my CSS.  Adding `background-size` in after the PHP solved my issue.  I posted my answer with my findings for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to figure out my issue thanks to some hints from @jkon and @EduardoEscobar.

When overriding my CSS in the `<head>` tag, I thought I would only need to override the one command that I was changing, but it seems I needed to also include the rest of the other CSS commands.

In my CSS, my `.fullscreen` class looked like this:

```
.fullscreen {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212121; 
    background: url('http://pathToImage.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px #000000;
}
```

and in my index.php `<head>` tag, I was overriding just the background URL with PHP like so:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fullscreen{ background: url('<?php getHeroImage(); ?>') no-repeat center center;}
    </style>
</head>
```

But what I should have been doing was including all the other CSS code.  This is what ended up getting the same result as just my CSS hardcoded URL:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fullscreen{ background: url('<?php getHeroImage(); ?>') no-repeat center center;
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px #000000;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #212121; 
                }
</style>
```

Thanks everyone for your feedback and help!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh... looks like I can't set this as the answer for another two days because I answered my own question?  Come on S.O.  Thats silly.

Comment: One thing to note is you should be able to do what you were trying to do (override just the background-image). But you have to include the base css code earlier in your document. That is why it is called cascading style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I know you found the answer to your problem but I just wanted to expand on my comment to your answer.

You should be able to override just the background-image. You just have to include the base css declaration and then override just the background-image in another declaration.

For example:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Base css code */
        .fullscreen {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #212121; 
            background: url('http://pathToImage.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 45px #000000;
        }

        /* Override the background image */
        .fullscreen{ 
            background: url('<?php getHeroImage(); ?>') no-repeat center center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("asdkfasdf.php");?>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fullscreen{background: url('asdfasdf.jpg');}
    </style>
</head>
<div class="fullscreen">asfdasdf</div>
</body>
<?php 
    if($imageCSS !== null || $imageCSS !== ''){
        echo '<style type="text/css">
             .fullscreen{background: url(\''.$imageCSS.'\');}
             </style>';
    }
?>
</html>

asadfasdf.php
<?php
function getHeroImage(){

$h = opendir('./Hero_Image/'); //Open the current directory
    while (false !== ($heroImage = readdir($h))) {
        if($heroImage != '.' && $heroImage != '..') {
            $heroFileInfo = pathinfo($heroImage);
            $heroImagePath = $heroFileInfo['dirname'];
            $heroImageBase = $heroFileInfo['basename'];
            // $heroImageFullPath = $heroImagePath.$heroImageBase;
            $imageCSS = './Hero_Image/'.$heroImageBase.' ';
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

i don't recommend having php on the bottom, but this works.  You shouldn't be echoing out a whole page that space.  include the page, and echo only the link.